Is this a plausible way to test the limits of parallelism in a subset of an organization's data?
If I aim to upload 10,000,000 records using the Bulk API with a batch size of 10,000, could I follow the procedure below?

Create a partial sandbox environment with a normalized subset of the object data that my import will interact with.
Set the batch size to 10,000 records for Bulk API operations.
Initiate the upload of 5 batches, each containing 10,000 records.
Monitor the upload for any contention or locking errors.

If no contention errors are observed with 50,000 records in the partial sandbox, is it likely that I'll encounter them in production? Why or why not?

Contention occurs when parallel transactions attempt to lock the same records (including parent records). There is a Help article that you should reference. In particular, sorting by parent record.
